# Can HttpClient PCL be used from another PCL in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, portable-class-library, dotnet-httpclient

Earlier I posted [an error report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210983/httpclient-inside-pcl-throws-notimplementedexception-when-called-from-a-silverli) about exception raised by HttpClient when it is used from another portable class library in a Silverlight application. Here is [another thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e0ff676-7983-4b5f-8ca0-a03553c3125a/http-stack-exception-using-wcf-ds-client-pcl-in-silverlight?forum=adodotnetdataservices) about a similar problem.

To investigate and better illustrate the problem I've built a tiny Silverlight app that only attempts to make an HTTP request using Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package (HttpClient library). The test code is very easy:

```
public class HttpClientRunner
{
    public Task<string> ExecuteRequestAsync()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return client.GetStringAsync("http://someurl/");
        }
    }
}
```

1. When I include this code in a Silverlight application or Silverlight class library, it works fine.
2. When I include this code in a portable class library (NET45+SL5+WinPhone8+Win8, I also tried other profiles), and call it from a Silverlight 5, then it throws an exception about not supported custom credential.
3. I've found a workaround and added a line WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp) prior calling test code above. This helped eliminating credentials exception, but now I am getting NotImplemented exception about the method System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.set_AllowAutoRedirect.

For the time being I gave up an idea of calling HttpClient from a PCL. I linked C# files from a Silverlight project, and then it worked. But this behaviour is a sign of something wrong with HttpClient PCL implementation on a Silverlight platform. I wonder if anyone succeeded with the scenario when HttpClient is called from another PCL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reference the Microsoft.Net.Http NuGet package from the SL5 app that was referencing the PCL?

Comment: Yes, both the PCL and the SL5 app included Microsoft.Net.Http in its package list. I also tried to install Microsoft.Net.Http into the Web site that hosted SL5 app but that didn't help (and I believe wasn't necessary).